# Free web servers to publish csv files or other types of data

Tags: iphone

I am writing an App that requires some kind of outside input which I want the user to be able to update sporadically.

Are there any free web services where one can upload a file e.g. CSV and update it at any stage and then access it via iOS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about dropbox? Its free for small amounts and has a desktop and IOS client. It also has a fairly decent API.

http://www.dropbox.com

Comment: I want the file to be loaded and displayed in a tableview, so I want the app to be able to read and maybe write to the file.  I don't want to simply display a file.  Is this possible with DropBox?

Comment: Yes. You can use the API to alter the file and read from it as well.